# Unferenced local variable? But I can print it alright

Tags: python, slice

For the life of me I do not understand why I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'unsorted' referenced before assignment (while len(unsorted) > 0)
```

For this code, I'm also aware it's not the best implementation of selection sort:

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    unsorted = arr[:]
    sorted_arr = []
    while len(unsorted) > 0:
        lowest = arr[0]
        lowest_index = 0
        for i in range(len(unsorted)):
            if arr[i] < lowest:
                lowest = arr[i]
                lowest_index = i

        sorted_arr.append(lowest)
        del(unsorted, lowest_index)
    return sorted_arr
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting this error because:

```
del(unsorted, lowest_index)
```

deletes the two variables `unsorted` and `lowest_index`, then at your next loop turn, you're trying to use them again.

Answer (score 0):

`del (unsorted, lowest_index)` deletes unsorted and lowest_index.  if you are trying to delete the element lowest_index in unsorted do:

```
del unsorted[lowest_index]
```